# MySQL how can i select 1 city per state that must have at least 1M people in it?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
City         State     Population    area      zip
New city      LA         10000        +33     12345
City2         NX        1000000       +48     33333
My city       LA        3000000       +12     43210
another city  EA          300         +99     99999
New city2     LA        1310000       +53     12345
City3         NX        5000000       +88     33833
```

and I want a result like this

```
City         State     Population    area      zip
City2         NX        1000000       +48     33333
My city       LA        3000000       +12     43210
```

Only one city can be shown per state and if there are no cities with a population bigger than a million that city/state won't show up.

I have tried `select distinct State from My_table where population>999999` but i only get the state not the rest of the information

Comment: this and client side code but it is far too slow to do it in the client sideSELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY state where population>999999) rn
        FROM    mytable
        )
WHERE   rn = 1

Comment: Won't work with MySQL - no windowing/analytic functions. Change to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Why is City3 not included in your result - City3 has a greater population than City2 - 5 million as opposed to 1000000?

Comment: because the STATE NX is already in the result

Comment: if "because the STATE NX is already in the result" - You need little clarify logic. You need ANY city with > 1M, You need first in list City, or biggest as mean in question of @Vérace

Comment: i need it to show only 1 city per state that have more than 1M ppl so if city2 is in NX and is before city3 that also has more than 1M ppl only city2 will show up because NX is already in the result so no repeated states so it is the first in the list

Comment: The problem with "city2 before city3" is that nothing seems to indicate that order. Yes, you've shown the rows that way in your example, but, in case you are not aware, there is no guarantee that order is preserved every time you retrieve the rows – unless your query has an ORDER BY clause (which you haven't mentioned).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Vérace, MySQL doesn't offer any of the good stuff that would make this easy, such as windowing function and common table expressions (or even just a `RANK()` function).

```
CREATE TABLE Cities
(
  City VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  State VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  Population INT NOT NULL,
  Area VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  Zip VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Cities (City, State, Population, Area, Zip)
VALUES
('New city',      'LA',         10000,        '+33',     '12345'),
('City2',         'NX',        1000000,       '+48',     '33333'),
('My city',       'LA',        3000000,       '+12',     '43210'),
('another city',  'EA',          300,         '+99',     '99999'),
('New city2',     'LA',        1310000,       '+53',     '12345'),
('City3',         'NX',        5000000,       '+88',     '33833');
```

However, with a bit of hackery it can be done (but really you should switch to a real database):

```
SELECT with_rank2.* FROM
(
  SELECT State, MIN(Rank) AS Lowest_Rank FROM
  (
    SELECT Cities.*, @current_rank := @current_rank + 1 AS Rank
    FROM Cities, (SELECT @current_rank := 0) r
  ) with_rank
  WHERE Population >= 1000000
  GROUP BY State
  ORDER BY State, Rank
) lowest_rank_per_state
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Cities.*, @current_rank2 := @current_rank2 + 1 AS Rank
  FROM Cities, (SELECT @current_rank2 := 0) r
) with_rank2
ON lowest_rank_per_state.Lowest_Rank = with_rank2.Rank
```

(I didn't say it was going to be pretty, did I?)

What this does: the `with_rank` and `with_rank2` subselects (which are identical) give each city a unique ID of sorts based on the order on which I inserted the rows. This is because you mentioned that the city to be selected should be “the first in the list”, but there's nothing in the list to actually see if it is “first”.

Then, the aggregate (`GROUP BY`) subselect picks the lowest-ranked number (corresponding to the earliest city in that state in your list), as long as that city has a population >= 1000000. (By the way, you mentioned that you only want to show cities with a population > 1000000, but your example output shows a city with population=1000000, so I assumed you meant >= 1000000.)

Finally, the results of this aggregate subselect are joined back to another ranked list to get all the columns that you're interested in.

See also http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19c83/13/0

Comment: Could you look at [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96d3b/1/0) and [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcf45/2) - how does the ranking work? It seems to go by order of insertion into the table.

Comment: See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84247/1) for a puzzler with your SQL - where does the rank of 8 come from for Miami - should it not be 2? We have 3 cities from states that have a population >= 1000,000 from different states (excluding CA and NY).

Comment: That was exactly the point of the ranking, to make the insert order explicit, since @jac mentioned that he wanted “the first in the list”, but his data doesn't contain any ordering other than insert order.